# using array as alternative of Set

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

For example, we have visitors coming, and we’d like to remember everyone. But repeated visits should not lead to duplicates. A visitor must be “counted” only once.
using set will be like that :

```js
const set = new Set();
const sara = { name: 'sara' };
const leyla = { name: 'leyla' };
const mera = { name: 'mera' };
set.add(sara);
set.add(mera);
set.add(leyla);
set.add(sara);
set.add(mera);

for (let user of set) {
   console.log(user);
}
```

instead of set I want to use array of users 
and to check for duplicate i use arr.find() 
what is the code for this ?

Comment: you'd use `array.find` as documented to check if the array has the value you are looking for - try it, it's easy, if you have a problem, then show what you tried - don't think stack overflow is a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for a `name` already in existence, use `find`:

```
if (!arr.some(({ name }) => name === obj.name)) arr.push(obj);
```

```js
function addUniq(arr, obj) {
  if (!arr.some(({ name }) => name === obj.name)) arr.push(obj); 
}

const uniqArr = [];
const sara = { name: 'sara' };
const leyla = { name: 'leyla' };
const mera = { name: 'mera' };
addUniq(uniqArr, sara);
addUniq(uniqArr, mera);
addUniq(uniqArr, leyla);
addUniq(uniqArr, sara);
addUniq(uniqArr, mera);

uniqArr.forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You could also add that method directly onto the `Array.prototype` object:

```js
Array.prototype.addUniq = function(obj) {
  if (!this.some(({ name }) => name === obj.name)) this.push(obj); 
}

const uniqArr = [];
const sara = { name: 'sara' };
const leyla = { name: 'leyla' };
const mera = { name: 'mera' };
uniqArr.addUniq(sara);
uniqArr.addUniq(mera);
uniqArr.addUniq(leyla);
uniqArr.addUniq(sara);
uniqArr.addUniq(mera);

uniqArr.forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```